# XDELETE not deleting index in ElasticSearch

Tags: powershell, elasticsearch

I have created two files that are,

`jdbc_sqlserver.json`:

```json
{
    "type": "jdbc",
    "jdbc": {
        "url": "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=merchant2merchant;integratedSecurity=true;",
        "user": "",
        "password": "",
        "sql": "select * from planets",
        "treat_binary_as_string": true,
        "elasticsearch": {
            "cluster": "elasticsearch",
            "host": "localhost",
            "port": 9200
        },
        "index": "testing"
    }
```

`jdb_sqlserver.ps1`:

```cs
function Get-PSVersion {
    if (Test-Path variable:PSVersionTable) {
        $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
    } else {
        [version]"1.0.0.0"
    }
}

$powershell = Get-PSVersion
if ($powershell.Major -le 2) {
    Write-Error "Oh, so sorry, this script requires Powershell 3 (due to ConvertTo-Json)"
    exit
}
if ((Test-Path env:\JAVA_HOME) -eq $false) {
    Write-Error "Environment variable JAVA_HOME must be set to your java home"
    exit
}
curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/users/"
$DIR = "C:\Program Files\elasticsearch\plugins\elasticsearch-jdbc-2.3.4.0-dist\elasticsearch-jdbc-2.3.4.0\"
$FEEDER_CLASSPATH = "$DIR\lib"
$FEEDER_LOGGER = "file://$DIR\bin\log4j2.xml"

java -cp "$FEEDER_CLASSPATH\*" -Dlog4j.configurationFile=$FEEDER_LOGGER"
    "org.xbib.tools.Runner"
    "org.xbib.tools.JDBCImporter"
    jdbc_sqlserver.json
```

I am confused that in ElasticSearch XDELETE is used delete index while it is creating index.

Comment: It's `-X DELETE`, not `XDELETE` (i.e. calling the HTTP [DELETE](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.7) method). Are you actually using [`curl`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL), or are you using the `curl` alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`? Are you getting an error? Can you describe the actual as well as the desired result in more detail?

Comment: I am not getting error actually  .....after getting response Acknowledgement : True I check on browser by refreshing http://localhost:9200:/testing first time it shows like Index has been deleted but refreshing it again same index appears again if I check http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v on browser ..it's really annoying for me

Comment: I am using Powershell to run the curl command where i am importing sql data using jdbc importer through MSSQL ...One more thing i check the liknk og elasticsearch https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/indices-delete-index.html it shows me curl -XDELETE rather than -X DELETE ....Please suggest ..Your help will be appriciable

Answer (score 3):

I also first tried to get the copy-pasteable snippet-curl-commands from [elastic.co](http://elastic.co) to work in PowerShell (In Version 4). PowerShell has an alias for curl ([as discussed here](https://superuser.com/q/344927/251218)), but it does not follow the same syntax it seems.

So in my opinion it is better to convert the `curl`-calls to `Invoke-WebRequest`-calls altogether.

To delete an index, using PowerShell, just use this command

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://localhost:9200/users/' -Method Delete
```

(translated from `curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/users/"`)